# Existence of joint probability distribution (hidden variables) for partially compatible measurements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, probability, quantum-interpretations, mathematics

**Informal summary:** If we have $n$ measurements out of which we apply at most $q$, and we know that up to $q$ measurements commute on a given starting state, is there a hidden variable model that explains up to $q$ measurements?

**Formal description of the problem:**
Fix a quantum state $\lvert\Psi_0\rangle\in\mathcal H$, and $n$ projective binary measurements $P_1,\dots,P_n$ (represented by projectors). Let $\mathbb P$ denote the set of all those measurements.

Assume that up to $q$ of those measurements commute on $\lvert\Psi_0\rangle$. Formally: If $Q_1,\dots,Q_q\in\mathbb P$ and $R_1,\dots,R_q\in\mathbb P$ are the same measurements up to reordering, then $Q_q\dots Q_1\lvert\Psi_0\rangle=R_q\dots R_1\lvert\Psi_0\rangle$.

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ denote random variables corresponding to the outcomes of the measurements $P_1,\dots,P_n$. Due to the commutativity property above, for any subset of $q$ variables $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$, the joint distribution $\mathcal D_I$ of those $q$ variables is well-defined (since the the distribution of up to $q$ measurements does not depend on the order of those measurements).

Question: Does a joint probability distribution $\mathcal D$ on $X_1,\dots,X_n$ exist such that the distribution $\mathcal D_I$ is the marginal of $\mathcal D$ for every $I$ of size $q$?

**Comment 1:** If we require that the $P_i$ commute pairwise (instead of commuting for a single fixed starting state $\lvert\Psi_0\rangle$), the problem is trivial because then the $P_i$ diagonalize jointly.

**Comment 2:** I am also happy with the existence of a joint distribution $\mathcal D$ such that the marginals exist for every set $I$ of size $q^{1/c}$ for some constant $c>0$ (instead of size $q$).

**Comment 3:** I am also happy if this holds for suitably large $q$ only (but $q$ not larger than $(\log \dim \mathcal H)^c$ for some constant $c>0$).

**Comment 4:** I am also happy if this holds approximately, that is, the marginals of $\mathcal D$ are close to the $\mathcal D_I$ (as long as the $L_1$-distance is 1/superpolynomial in $q$).

Comment: To be clear, the hypothesis states that *any* set of q projectors will commute?

Comment: Yes, any set of $q$. But they only commute on the specific state $\lvert \Psi\rangle_0$.